# Are dictionary and set datatypes some how related in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, set, unique

Are dictionary and set datatypes some how related in python? Considering that they both have no order, take unique values, and use "{ }" for their representation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The `set` datatype is based on (implemented using) the `dict` datatype. But this has nothing to do with the `{}` notation. The `{}` notation for `dicts` has been part of Python since Python 1.5.2 (probably before that, but that was before my time). The `{}` notation for sets is very new.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Do you happen to have a source where I can read the details of how set is built based on dictionary?

Comment: As far as I recall, Greg Wilson and Raymond Hettinger wrote the `set` class, and Raymond was also much involved in a recent reimplementation of `dict`. The original proposal was PEP 218: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0218/ but if you want more details you would need to approach the authors of of the class. I take it that you don't want to plunge into reading the actual code. 
Oh, and if you liked the answer, please accept it.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply. I'm a newcomer to Stack Overflow. I clicked on the checkmark next to your answer. I hope that is how I should accept your answer. Please let me know.